# How to animate label's value in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, label

I am making a slot machine game in iphone. I am using cocos2d as its language. I am greatly disturb coding for the method that will animate score in the game. The animation looks like with the fps. Can you help me do it. Animating the score in cocos2d. Can you share sample code that looks like what i need now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are you trying to do? Animate a Label to do what? Like a typewriter effect?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do my score.  it is not really animated, but if you want it to be like fps this will do it.  Just call this method when your score changes.

in your init method:

```
    // create and initialize the _scoreLabel
    _scoreLabel = [CCLabel  labelWithString:@" "
                            dimensions:CGSizeMake(labelSizes.width,labelSizes.height)
                            alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft
                            fontName:@"Helvetica"
                            fontSize:20.0];
    _scoreLabel.color = ccc3(255,255,255);
    _scoreLabel.position = ccp((labelSizes.width / 2), (winSize.height - (labelSizes.height / 2)));
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel z:1];
```

This is the score update method:

```
-(void)updateScore {
    [_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d / %d", _score, _scoreToWin]];
}
```

Then to update the score when the score changes call it like this:

```
    // Then later to set the Score
    [self updateScore];
```

Comment: this one just update the score only know!!!he need to animate  the score visually!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in this way:

```
 _odd = _odd + _stage*value;
 [self schedule:@selector(pointAdder) interval:1.0/(3.0*_odd)];
```

and

```
- (void)pointAdder {
    if (_odd==0) {
        [self unschedule:@selector(pointAdder)];
        return;
    }
    else {
        int tmp = [_lblScore.string intValue];
        [_lblScore setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",tmp+1]];
        _odd--;
    }
}
```